# Matlab - Checking if an element is empty in a struct

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have the following code in `matlab`

```
function test
C = struct;
    C.(sprintf('C%d',1)) = 1;
    C.(sprintf('C%d',2)) = [];
    if C.(sprintf('C%d',2)) == []
        disp('C2 is empty...')
    end
end
```

I just want to check if `C.(sprintf('C%d',2))` is an empty matrix. But, when I run the program as follows:

```
>> test
```

I don't get any results back.

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if C.(sprintf('C%d',2)) == []
```

you should use

```
if isempty(C.(sprintf('C%d',2)))
```